# Which substitution to do?

Tags: calculus

I want to integrate this:

$${\int}{\frac{{\sin{\theta}}~\cos{\theta}~d{\theta}}{{(a^{2}+2b\cos{\theta})^{3/2}}}}$$

where $a$ and $b$ are constants. The integration interval is from $o$ to ${\pi}$.

Which substitution could I do?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Let $u = a^2 + 2b \cos{\theta}$, so that $$\cos{\theta} = \frac{u - a^2}{2b}$$ and $$-\frac{du}{2b} = \sin{\theta} d\theta$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly longer computation, but may be clearer. Working first with the denominator

$a^2 $ +2bcosx = $a^2 $ (1 + 2bcosx/a<sup>2</sup>)  = a<sup>2</sup>(1 + dcosx)  = $a^2 $[ (1+dcosx)$^2$ - d$^2$cos$^2$x] where d = b/a<sup>2</sup>

Let u = dcosx. Then the integral becomes
 d/a$^3$$\int$udu/[u$^2$ - (1+u)$^2$]<sup>3/2</sup>

The denominator factors into [u +(1+u)][u-(1+u)] = -(2u+1).  So the integral becomes
C$\int$udu/(2u+1)<sup>3/2</sup> where C represents all the constants.

Next let v = 2u +1  so we have C/2$\int$[(v-1)/2]dv/v<sup>3/2</sup> = K$\int$(v<sup>-1/2</sup> - v<sup>-3/2</sup>)dv where K represents the accumulated constants.

At this point it should be very clear.  The trickiest part is getting the constants right.